# Cesium multiple material for polyline

Tags: cesium

I am trying to draw a glow arrow in Cesium. In the Cesium examples they show how to draw polyline as glow polyline or as arrow by set material.

How can I combine more then one material so I will be able to draw a polyline that will be shown as glow arrow?